How to Force a restore on Whatsapp
I purchased a new phone.  Both old and new ones are Samsung.  As always, Samsung Switch does not transfer data for apps with security.

I tried to transfer the WhatsApp account over to the new phone.
It crashed saying the backup was not valid.
So, I switched back to the old phone (there are a few bugs in this process, but I succeeded).
I have pruned some data, to make the next backup smaller
I found how to start the backup manually and performed it.
I went back to the new phone and transferred the account

This time it did not even try to do a restore.  How do I make it restore from the backup?

Possible dupe: WhatsApp doesn't prompt to restore from local storage

@AndrewT.  It is different in that I am still using the same number. and I am switching to a comparable phone of the same brand.

These were my issues and eventual solutions.

The last backup had apparently failed, so couldn't be restored from. 
Solution : Always do a manual backup first (and include videos if so wish).
Once a restore has failed, restarting WhatsApp does no good, it acts as if the restore had worked. 
Solution: Delete Cache and Data in Settings>App>WhatsApp, uninstall it and reinstall it.  The restore then happens automatically.
While WhatsApp is in a mis-state it may not give you the code for authentication to transfer between the phones. 
Solution:  Use the Try another method and use email or phone number to get the code.

